# A detail in the proof that a group of order 168 is simple

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I am doing an excercise from Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra that wants me to prove that the group $PSL(2,Z_7)$ is simple. I have reached the point $n_2=7$, $n_3=7$ or $28$ and $n_7=8$.

I found some hints to this problem and one hint to prove $n_3$ cannot be $7$ was that no element of order $7$ can normalize a Sylow $3$ subgroup.

My questions are two:

1. Gallian does not use the verb 'to normalize'. I am guessing it means that conjugating the subgroup by this element gives back the subgroup. Correct?
2. Can anyone give a hint as to why an element of order 7 does not normalize a Sylow 3 subgroup?

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.
≈========
Edit.
I think I found the answer to question 2 if the answer to 1 is 'yes'. Let x be an element of order 7. If x normalizes the subgroup then it is an element of its normalizer. If $n_3=$ 7 then the order of the normalizer is 24. And since 7 does not divide 24 x cannot be an element of said normalizer and we are done. Is this correct?

Comment: Normalize does indeed mean lies in the normalizer of, so $x$ normalizes $H$ if $H^x=H$. If an element of order $7$ normalized a subgroup of order $3$ then $7\mid |N_G(P)|$, where $P$ is a Sylow $3$-subgroup. But then $7\nmid |G:N_G(P)|=n_3$. I don't see how this allows you to eliminate either $7$ or $28$ from being $n_3$.

Comment: As an aside, are you trying to prove that $PSL_2(7)$ is simple, or that there exists a simple group of order $168$, or determining the number of Sylows in $PSL_2(7)$, or determining the number of Sylows in a simple group of order $168$, or proving that a simple group of order $168$ is $PSL_2(7)$?

Comment: Thanks David. Your post confirms my edit. And I want to prove $PSL(2,Z_7)$ is simple.